# PyQt5: How to update siblings in QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qabstractitemmodel

I am working on a Python-application (WinPython 3.4.3.2) with PyQt5 and use QAbstractItemModel.

I have designed several widgets to work on the data. The two pictures of the GUI indicate one example. Depending on the selected channel type, the meaning of the input parameter changes: Some of the "input" parameter even can change from "input" parameter to calculated values (like the hydraulic diameter which depend on inner and outer diameter, for future version some of the input parameters are set to inactive depending on selected channel type).

[image: State 1 of widget, the hydraulic diameter and cross sectional area is calculated based on inner and outer diameter]
[image: State 2 of widget, the hydraulic diameter and cross sectional area are to be input by the user, inner and outer diameter will be set inactive (not implemented yet).]

After change of the channel type, or change in inner diameter, some of the fields (or better all) have to be updated by the code.

I have implemented this as follows in the setData function:

```
class SimulationDataModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    """INPUTS: Node, QObject"""
    def __init__(self, root=None, parent=None, filename=None):
        super(SimulationDataModel, self).__init__(parent)

    ....

    """INPUTS: QModelIndex, QVariant, int (flag)"""
    def setData(self,index,value, role=Qt.EditRole):

        if index.isValid():
            node = index.internalPointer()
            typeInfo = node.typeInfo()
            if role == Qt.EditRole:
                node.setData(index.column(),value)
                if typeInfo == "CHANNEL":
                    self.dataChanged.emit(index.sibling(index.row(),2) ,index.sibling(index.row(),14))
                else:
                    self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
                self._dirty = True
                return True   
        return False
```

That means, that for part of the model, I emit a dataChanged signal for all the siblings, so that the data is read from the model and all the widgets/spinboxes are updated.

The problem is that I ran into severe performance problem:

The cProfiler stats:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     3   17.727    5.909   17.735    5.912 {method 'emit' of 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtBoundSignal' objects}
     1    6.479    6.479   26.203   26.203 {built-in method exec_}
     1    1.916    1.916    7.645    7.645 {question}
```

If I change the code line with the dataChanged.emit to the following, I do not run into the performance problems.

```
if typeInfo == "CHANNEL":
    self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
else:
    self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
```

But for sure, the other widgets/spinboxes are no longer updated imidiately.

I have the following questions:

Is there another way to update the complete model (or part of it) after one data item has been changed?
What could be the reason for the long time per call in method emit?
What is the difference between the pyQtSignal and the pyQtBoundSignal?

I have to admit: The performance problems do not occur in each application run, sometimes (approx. 70 %) they occur, sometimes not and up to now, I haven't found any pattern, when it happens. Furthermore the complete GUI is very slow.

And up to now, I could not create a minimal working example, where I could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you connecting to the `dataChanged` signal?  What do your slot functions look like?  The overhead in emitting the `dataChanged` signal should be minimal, but your "refresh" functions that are listening to the signal could be very expensive and redundant.